# Given the output C of the function H(A, B) = (A ^ B) ^ ((A & B) << 1), how to write a function that outputs A given C and B?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Assuming that `a` and `b` are unsigned integers, consider the following function:

```
function H(a, b) {
    var c = (a ^ b) ^ ((a & b) << 1);
    return c
};
```

The description of this function can be found in NORX specification (the links are available at [this page](https://github.com/norx/resources)).

I need to implement the **reverse** function of `H` (in Javascript). That is, given `c` and `b`, the function is required to output `a`.

The specification provides an algorithm for the reverse function (assuming that `v[i]` denotes an `i`-th bit of an integer `v`):

```
a[0] = c[0] XOR b[0];
a[1] = (c[1] XOR b[1]) XOR (a[0] AND b[0]);
...
a[i] = (c[i] XOR b[i]) XOR (a[i-1] AND b[i-1]);
```

But I don't know how to implement it.

I tried the following function (note that the arguments are the elements of UintNArrays, so we assume that `N` is either 8 or 16 or 32):

```
function revH(c, b) {
    var x = (c ^ b) >>> 0; var a = x;

    for (var i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        x0 = (c ^ b) ^ ( (a >>> i) & (b >>> i )); 
        a = (a & ~(0x1 << i)) | ((x >>> (N-i)) << i);
    };
    return a
};
```

But this function is not correct (it does not output correct results). How to implement the reverse function of `H`?

Comment: *"The specification provides an algorithm for the reverse function, but I don't understand how to implement it."* Add it to the question plz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my quick attempt at it:

```
function revH(c, b) {
    var cxorb = c ^ b;
    var a = cxorb & 0x1;
    for (var i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        var x0 = cxorb & (0x1 << i);
        var x1 = (a & (0x1 << (i-1))) & (b & (0x1 << (i-1)));
        a = a | (x0 ^ (x1 << 1));
    }
    return a;
}
```

Where `N` is the size in bits of your integers.

Comment: I just noticed a mistake in the code, `x1` needed to be bit-shifted by 1 to the left. I've edited the code to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Another version based on the bit equations, from bit 0, bit 1 then bit *i*

> c<sub>0</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> ⊕ b<sub>0</sub>
>   c<sub>1</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> ⊕ b<sub>1</sub> ⊕ a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>0</sub>
>   ...
>   c<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i</sub> ⊕ b<sub>i</sub> ⊕ a<sub>i-1</sub>b<sub>i-1</sub>

To find *a* from *b* and *c*, based on these equations thanks to ⊕ properties

> a<sub>0</sub> = c<sub>0</sub> ⊕ b<sub>0</sub>
>   a<sub>1</sub> = c<sub>1</sub> ⊕ b<sub>1</sub> ⊕ a<sub>0</sub>b<sub>0</sub>
>   ...
>   a<sub>i</sub> = c<sub>i</sub> ⊕ b<sub>i</sub> ⊕ a<sub>i-1</sub>b<sub>i-1</sub>

Which allows us to write a small program (32 bits here) that does exactly the same as in the equation

```
const int N = 32;

unsigned revH(unsigned c, unsigned b) {
     unsigned a = (c ^ b) & 1;     // bit 0
     for(int i=1 ; i<N ; i++) {    // bit i
          a |= ((c ^ b) & (1<<i)) ^ (((a & b) & (1<<(i-1))) << 1);
     }
    return a;
}
```